# Facebook api-why do i need a token?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have read almost all the `graph API` and i don't get this thing at all .
I am some user, who needs to get some other public page photos . thats it,very simple.
So to do that, i can just :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/page id/photos/uploaded/
```

Which is works great. gives a json with the photos .

BUT ,Facebook is always talks about this `tokens` everywhere. you need a `token` to everything .
So after so much frustration i have got this token i created to some app i made.

Problem is, what i do with this token ?? i don't see any place in the API where i put this token in the http request .

Take this request i showed here for example, it works for any page without a token. so where goes the token? why do i need it ?

Why when talking about getting images of some page they always say you must be the admin of that page? NO I DONT want to be the admin of a page, i just want to get photos of other page, that i don't own, with a simple http request.

Everything is messed up for me .

Answer (score 0):

You can apply an `access_token` to any Graph API request by appending `?access_token=xxx` to the URL. In your example, the resulting URL would be:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/page id/photos?access_token=xxx
```

The access_token is typically used to access any data that isn't public. While its true that you don't need an `access_token` or be an Admin of a page to get Photos, you may still need an `access_token` to access pages with location or age restrictions.

For example, I can easily get public photos from the Coca Cola page:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/photos
```

But not for this protected page (since you must be 18+ to access this page):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/Betfair/photos
```